# JS Fiddle duplicating a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I am trying to get an example using dynatable to work in JSFiddle.

I have found an example here http://jsfiddle.net/brandonzylstra/G4m95/ copy pasted all the code to a personal project:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#local').dynatable({
      dataset: {
        records: JSON.parse($('#music').text())
      }
    });

    // getting JSON from a remote source fails:
    $('#remote').dynatable({
      dataset: {
        ajax: true,
        ajaxOnLoad: true,
        ajaxUrl: '//www.dynatable.com/dynatable-ajax.json',
        records: []
      }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vbiter/3g9dxy42/

Nothing happens. The data isn't loaded. I'd hazard that it's the external references, but they're identical to the ones used in the sample.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't selected jquery in your new fiddle. Do that and it should work fine.

Here's how you select that:

[image]